# Find next prime in C?

Tags: c

I create a function that returns the next prime number greater or equal to the number given as an argument and my code works well but I have one issue when I run multiple tests I got a long run time.
the run time takes almost 60s and I want less than 10s.

This link https://ibb.co/pRRbd6K can help to understand is the subject

**Rules:**

Do not use a library or a for loop, no externe function Allowed.

**Code**

Is this algorithm can be optimized or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int ft_is_prime(int nb)
{
     int    i;

    i = (int)nb - 1;
    if (nb <= 1)
        return (0);
    while (i > 1)
    {
        if (nb % i == 0)
            return (0);
        i--;
    }
    return (1);
}

int ft_find_next_prime(int nb)
{

    while (ft_is_prime(nb) == 0)
    {
        ft_is_prime(nb);
        nb++;
    }
    return (nb);
}
```

**Main**

I use this main to check how long take

```
int main()
{
    printf("%d -> %d\n", -1868, ft_find_next_prime(-1868));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 0, ft_find_next_prime(0));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 1, ft_find_next_prime(1));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 2, ft_find_next_prime(2));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 7853, ft_find_next_prime(7853));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 78989, ft_find_next_prime(78989));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 2147483643, ft_find_next_prime(2147483643));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 2147483645, ft_find_next_prime(2147483645));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 2147483646, ft_find_next_prime(2147483646));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 2147483647, ft_find_next_prime(2147483647));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 203785, ft_find_next_prime(203785));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 14357, ft_find_next_prime(14357));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 389654, ft_find_next_prime(389654));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 356376, ft_find_next_prime(356376));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 111641, ft_find_next_prime(111641));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 139803, ft_find_next_prime(139803));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 98368, ft_find_next_prime(98368));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 172597, ft_find_next_prime(172597));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 178697, ft_find_next_prime(178697));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 295994, ft_find_next_prime(295994));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 66107, ft_find_next_prime(66107));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 348224, ft_find_next_prime(348224));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 424018, ft_find_next_prime(424018));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 182868, ft_find_next_prime(182868));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 279638, ft_find_next_prime(279638));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 215132, ft_find_next_prime(215132));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 130734, ft_find_next_prime(130734));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 254567, ft_find_next_prime(254567));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 287850, ft_find_next_prime(287850));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 101486, ft_find_next_prime(101486));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 338034, ft_find_next_prime(338034));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 367221, ft_find_next_prime(367221));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 352888, ft_find_next_prime(352888));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 296057, ft_find_next_prime(296057));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 420476, ft_find_next_prime(420476));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 337541, ft_find_next_prime(337541));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 269965, ft_find_next_prime(269965));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 262287, ft_find_next_prime(262287));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 298128, ft_find_next_prime(298128));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 81045, ft_find_next_prime(81045));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 6816, ft_find_next_prime(6816));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 200353, ft_find_next_prime(200353));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 87717, ft_find_next_prime(87717));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 275623, ft_find_next_prime(275623));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 20140, ft_find_next_prime(20140));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 145069, ft_find_next_prime(145069));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 309422, ft_find_next_prime(309422));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 288966, ft_find_next_prime(288966));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 196808, ft_find_next_prime(196808));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 408696, ft_find_next_prime(408696));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 308434, ft_find_next_prime(308434));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 234200, ft_find_next_prime(234200));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 12514, ft_find_next_prime(12514));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 363758, ft_find_next_prime(363758));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 257776, ft_find_next_prime(257776));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 312563, ft_find_next_prime(312563));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 757, ft_find_next_prime(757));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 398583, ft_find_next_prime(398583));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 36608, ft_find_next_prime(36608));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 35590, ft_find_next_prime(35590));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 174862, ft_find_next_prime(174862));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 409874, ft_find_next_prime(409874));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 68893, ft_find_next_prime(68893));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 87838, ft_find_next_prime(87838));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 284334, ft_find_next_prime(284334));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 48416, ft_find_next_prime(48416));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 32034, ft_find_next_prime(32034));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 125232, ft_find_next_prime(125232));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 418100, ft_find_next_prime(418100));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 312630, ft_find_next_prime(312630));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 288568, ft_find_next_prime(288568));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 398662, ft_find_next_prime(398662));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 46407, ft_find_next_prime(46407));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 121678, ft_find_next_prime(121678));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 406867, ft_find_next_prime(406867));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 61269, ft_find_next_prime(61269));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 315739, ft_find_next_prime(315739));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 271203, ft_find_next_prime(271203));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 192870, ft_find_next_prime(192870));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 114535, ft_find_next_prime(114535));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 173417, ft_find_next_prime(173417));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 248682, ft_find_next_prime(248682));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 306029, ft_find_next_prime(306029));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 108921, ft_find_next_prime(108921));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 210815, ft_find_next_prime(210815));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 252289, ft_find_next_prime(252289));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 72584, ft_find_next_prime(72584));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 297710, ft_find_next_prime(297710));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 27544, ft_find_next_prime(27544));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 373150, ft_find_next_prime(373150));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 219888, ft_find_next_prime(219888));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 156579, ft_find_next_prime(156579));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 271274, ft_find_next_prime(271274));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 295751, ft_find_next_prime(295751));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 207022, ft_find_next_prime(207022));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 143794, ft_find_next_prime(143794));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 390643, ft_find_next_prime(390643));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 186808, ft_find_next_prime(186808));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 230330, ft_find_next_prime(230330));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 175035, ft_find_next_prime(175035));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 101832, ft_find_next_prime(101832));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 205261, ft_find_next_prime(205261));
    printf("%d -> %d\n",389070, ft_find_next_prime(389070));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 397788, ft_find_next_prime(397788));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 6117, ft_find_next_prime(6117));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 169448, ft_find_next_prime(169448));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 393706, ft_find_next_prime(393706));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 286195, ft_find_next_prime(286195));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 334329, ft_find_next_prime(334329));
    printf("%d -> %d\n", 184829, ft_find_next_prime(184829));
}
```

Comment: Yes, your `ft_is_prime()` could certainly be optimized. There are much better algorithms that don't need to check n -1 values. Related: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Pseudocode)

Comment: _"[Can] this algorithm be optimized or not?"_  It can.  Most code can.  If you are asking for suggestions, that may fare better at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: General rule of thumb: Do less work.

Comment: Your loop in `ft_find_next_prime` is gratuitously calling `ft_is_prime` an extra time for no reason at all.

Comment: For basic primality testing like you're doing here, the two absolutely basic optimizations are: (1) test trial divisors (variable `i` in your `ft_is_prime` function) only up to `sqrt(nb)`, and (2) test only *odd* divisors.  (Together, these mean you may need a special case `if(nb == 2) return 1`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see quite a bit of room for optimzation in your code.  First of all, all prime numbers greater than 2 are odd.  So you can make an even number odd by adding 1.  You can use something like this:

`nb += (nb & 0x00000001) ? 0 : 1;`

Add this before the line `i = (int)nb - 1;`.  On that line, you don't need the (int) typecast since the datatype is already int.

Another optimization is since you are only checking odd numbers, change the line `n--;` to `n -= 2;` so you decrement twice --OR-- you can use a for loop instead of a while loop:

```
for (i = nb; i > 1; i -= 2)
{
....
}
```

When working with prime numbers, you only need to check from 2 through the square root of the given number.  Given number y, y = x², therefore x = sqrt(y).  The square root is the highest number of nb where the multiplicands are unique.  Go higher than that and it repeats with the numbers reversed.  So take the square root, make the result odd, then run it through your loop.

```
int i, x;

x = (int)sqrt(nb);
x += (x & 0x00000001) ? 0 : 1;
for (i = x; i > 1; i -= 2)
{
    if ((x % i) == 0) return(0);
}
return(1);
```

You will need `#include <math.h>` and depending on your compiler, you may need the -lm switch when you compile it (math library for the sqrt() function).

There are probably other optimizations, but that should get you started.

EDIT 08-20-2021@0313

Per the comment of the OP, no for loop and no functions.  So, the above code becomes what the OP had for the loop:

```
int i, x;

x = sqrti(nb);
x += (x & 0x00000001) ? 0 : 1;
i = x - 1;
while (i > 1)
{
    if ((x % i) == 0) return(0);
    i -= 2;
}
return(1);
```

And here's a square root function that will return an integer.

```
int sqrti(x)
{
    float n, pn;
    int i, r, f = 0;

    if (x < 0)
    {
        x = -x;
        f = 1;
    }

    n = x >> 1;
    pn = -1;
    i = 20;

    while (n != pn && i > 0)
    {
        pn = n;
        n = 0.5 * (n + (x / n));
        i--;
    }

    if (f == 1) r = (int)(-n - 0.5);
        else r = (int)(n + 0.5);

    return(r);
}
```

Depending on how far you are in your math studies, the square root function is a special case of Newton's Method that comes from Calculus.  Floats are used to calculate the square root itself and it is then converted to integer.  We add/subtract 0.5 to the answer for rounding.  n is set to 1/2 of x as an initial guess. The while loop compares the current n with the previous n (n != pn).  If they are equal, then the calculation has converged on a number and that's our answer.  The i counter is to prevent an infinite loop in the very rare case that the function does not converge.  The only time that *I* have ever seen that happen is with a negative x.  The square root of negative numbers does not exist, hence they are known as imaginary numbers.  This function will handle negative numbers and will return a negative square root for a negative number although that's not exactly mathematically correct.  One could use the negative as an indicator that the number is imaginary.

The basic function (without the negative number handling) is what calculators use to compute it.  Now you have a square root function you can modify and use in your other code.  This should really speed up your code by quite a bit.

Comment: Thank you a lot that was helpful but I  don't have permission to use a library or a for loop, no externe function **Allowed functions: None** .

Comment: @YassinAmjad I modified the answer and included an integer square root function for you to use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are making a number of very basic mistakes.

Here:

```
while (ft_is_prime(nb) == 0)
{
    ft_is_prime(nb);  <---------- Absolutely unnecessary! Just delete.
    nb++;
}
```

That should save you half of the execution time.

Now in `ft_is_prime` your loop test from high numbers to low number. **That's a real bad idea.**

For instance if the function is called with value 100, your code checks all the value 99, 98, 97, 96, ... which is absolutely unnecessary.

All you need to check is 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 as square root of 100 is 10.

In other words - your current code checks ~90 numbers that can't be a solution. They just burn CPU cycles for no use.

In fact you don't need all the even numbers - just the number 2. So you only need 9, 7, 5, 3, 2.

So instead of check numbers from high to low you should do:

- Start by checking 2
- Then in a loop you start from number 3. In each  loop increment by 2 (i.e. 3->5->7...). Stop the loop at square root of the argument.

There are algoritms to improve it further but if you do like this you'll get significant improvements. So try this first.